# Simultaneous equations and negative exponents

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am an elderly maths ignoramus! But trying to help my granddaughter with a problem. The simultaneous equations are:  $x^2 + y^2 = 25$  and $y - 3x = 13$. I have tried to get a value for y from equation b) in order to substitute it into a). But then I get to  $10x^2 = -144$ and I do not think x^2 can be a negative number! Is this correct? Can someone solve this simple (!) problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Note:  you can see geometrically that this system has real solutions.  The quadratic describes the circle of radius $5$ centered at the origin.  The line has points inside the circle, $\left(-\frac {13}3,0\right)$ for example, and it obviously has points outside the circle so it must intersect the circle in two points.

Comment: Thank you lulu. My brain, compared to yours, is a pea.

Comment: I didn't mean anything of the sort!  Especially with young students, I am a big believer in drawing pictures whenever possible.  At some point, pictures become unhelpful or even impossible, but where they can be drawn they strengthen insight.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2$ can be negative if imaginary numbers are allowed, e.g., $x^2 = -1$ means $x = \pm i$.  But we don't need to worry about that here.

$y - 3x = 13$ means $y = 3x + 13$.  Substitute this into the other equation.
\begin{align*}
  x^2 + y^2 &= 25\\
  x^2 + (3x + 13)^2 &= 25\\
  x^2 + 9x^2 + 78x + 169 &= 25\\
  10x^2 + 78x + 144 &= 0
\end{align*}
Divide both sides by $2$ to get $5x^2 + 39x + 72 = 0$.  This can be factored but since the numbers are bordering on the unpleasant, the quadratic formula may be a good way to go instead.

Comment: Thank you tilper. I will make further comments below!

Answer (score 0):

it is $$x^2+(3x+13)^2=25$$
$$x^2+9x^2+169+78x=25$$
Can you proceed?
write for $y$: $$y=3x+13$$
simplifying and factorizing we obtain
$$2\, \left( 5\,x+24 \right)  \left( x+3 \right) =0$$
from here you will get two cases:
$$5x+24=0$$ or $$x+3=0$$

Comment: Thank you Dr Graubner. But where do we go from here? I tried to use the quadratic formula as advised above and I got silly answers (ie x = -7.694 or x = -0.106), which do not make sense when put back into the original equations. (You are dealing, can I remind you, with a maths ignoramus.)

Comment: hello Martin, i have added some lines, is it clear now?

Comment: I scraped through my Maths O Level in the UK in about 1964! Many thanks to everyone who has tried to help me. It has shed a little light but if you can spare any more time to provide a solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: could you solve your problem?

Comment: So x = -4.8 or x = -3?  So can these values be confirmed by inserting them into the original equations?

Comment: yes you can check your equation if it's fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that a system of equations has no solutions but somewhere along the way, probably something went wrong in the calculations.
Substitution of $y=3x+13$ into $x^2+y^2=25$ gives:
$$x^2+(3x+13)^2=25 \iff 10 x^2 + 78 x + 144 = 0$$
which is a (standard) quadratic equation.

Although it's possible that this equation has no (real) solutions, that's not the case here.

Comment: Thank you StackTD. Is there any chance you might provide me with the solution? I cannot do it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have made a small arithmetical error. You used the second equation to get $y = 3x+13$, and then insertet this into the first equation to get $x^2 + (3x+13)^2 = 25$. Then from here, I suspect that you went directly for $x^2 + 9x^2 + 169 = 25$. This is a mistake. $(3x+13)^2$ and $9x^2 + 169$ are not the same thing.

I think this is best seen if you write $(3x+13)^2$ as $(3x+13)\cdot (3x+13)$ (this is what $^2$ means, after all), and then multiply the parentheses the long way. Because squaring is so common, many books teach you to just look at $(3x + 13)^2$ and immediately see that it's equal to $9x^2 + 26x + 169$ (usually through a formula like $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$). I suggest you only start to do that after having squares a few different brackets and seen how everything work.

So the actual equation you should solve is $10x^2 + 26x = -144$, or $10x^2 + 26x + 144 = 0$.

Side note: It is entirely possible for equations to have no solutions, particularily when the highest power the unknown is raised to is even. $10x^2 = -144$ is one example of this, as you rightly point out. There are number systems invented (or maybe discovered?) to deal with this. By far the most popular are the so-called *complex* numbers, which didn't get their name because they're difficult, but because they're put together from two parts. But for now it's safe to just say that there is no solution.

Comment: Thank you, Arthur. I'm not sure how you picked that up, but yes, I did make that error and I will try to learn how to square expressions properly!  Thank you for saying there is no solution, because at the moment I believe that to be true. But this was a question set by an exam board in the UK for 15 year olds. Why would they set something with no solution???

Comment: But the equation that doesn't have a solution is the one you got to by mistake. The actual equation you should've gotten does indeed have solutions. That being said, the possibility of the boy being any solutions is an important property of quadratic equations, and something students ought to be made aware of from the beginning in my opinion.

Comment: Any chance you could show me the solution and give me the values of x and y? I can't work it out at all.